# How can i send strings from a python (script) process to a C++ process running in Qt creator

Tags: python, c++, string, qt, ipc

I am working in Windows environment. I have a python script that sends commands to a device connected to the COM Port of my computer, and receives reply messages from that device. I want to send some of those received messages in the form of strings to my c++ application running on the Qt creator so that in Qt i could display that on my GUI.

I have tried sockets and pipes but could not find any support or any relevant example codes. QProcess class can display all standard output but i do not find anything related to inter process communication.

Comment: If you know python I think that a simpler option than what you propose is to use PyQt5 / PySide2 to create the GUI so you would not have 2 processes but only one.

Comment: You could use qwebsocket as python also has implementations of websockets.